# Laravel register custom macro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have custom macro such as *image_link* and I'm using that into `route.php` how to register this macro without defining this file? For example I must create a new model into `model` directory such as `Helpers`?

or how to define that into core laravel?

```
HTML::macro('image_link', function($url = '', $img='img/', $title ='' ,$alt='', $param = false, $active=true, $ssl=false)
{
    $url = $ssl==true ? URL::to_secure($url) : URL::to($url);  
    $img = HTML::image($img,$alt);
    $link = $active==true ? HTML::link($url, '#', $param) : $img;
    $link = str_replace('#', $img.$title ,$link);
    return $link;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a *app/lib* folder.
2. Then register this folder to be autoloaded by Laravel.
3. Create a new class app/lib/helper.php

A similar process is further explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106824/1165509). You just need to update your namespaces accordingly and replace that class with your class containing your helper methods.