# laravel 4 trait autoloading in models

Tags: laravel, models, autoload, traits

OK, I am struggling for over 2 hours now...

It must be one of the "oh god, it was that obvious" times where you are so tired and you cannot see the solution...

I want to extend the eloquentmodel to include a trait.

so my class looks like

```
<?php 
class Note extends Eloquent{
  use \Admin\GreatTrait;

  ...
}
```

and I created the `app/Traits/Admin` directory structure and there I created the  file named `GreatTrait.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php namespace Admin;

trait GreatTrait{
  ...
}
```

and of cource I edited the `start/global.php` to include the dir to the ClassLoader like so

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    ... more ...
    app_path().'/traits',
    app_path().'/traits/Admin',
));
```

and I get the following error...

`Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException`

`Trait 'Admin\GreatTrait' not found`

Anything to suggest?

Comment: Have you used `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 3):

Following your code, i made it work with next changes:

1. Include in composer.json this:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "app/traits"
       ] 
   }
   ```
2. Include in model after class declaration (just trait name, without
   directory):

   ```
   php 
   class Note extends Eloquent {
       use \GreatTrait;
       ...
   }
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with autoloading in global.php, you can do the same using copmposer.json:

Add the path to autoload array in *composer.json*

```
"autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "app/traits"
                ]
        },
```

Run `composer dump-autoload`

In *app/traits* path you should have the admin folder *app/traits/admin* with a class setting up the namespace Admin.

```
<?php
namespace Admin
class GreatTrait { ... }
```

Then you can use

```
<?php 
use \Admin\GreatTrait;
class Note extends Eloquent{

  ...
}
```